# ZipcodeSearchEngine result not completed

Tags: python

I am using the `ZipcodeSearchEngine()` to get a list of zip code for a certain state, but every time it only give me 5 results no matter what state/city I am using. My code as follow:

```
from uszipcode import ZipcodeSearchEngine

search = ZipcodeSearchEngine()

zipcodes = search.by_state("IL")

len(zipcode)
```

output:

```
5
```

Which there should be 56 zipcode listed.
Anyone knows how to fix this? Thanks

Comment: As the doc states, "Every search method support returns keyword to limit number of results to return. Zero is for unlimited. The default limit is 5."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the docs](http://pythonhosted.org/uszipcode/#by-state)

> You can add `returns=xxx` to set maxiumum number of zipcode can be returned. By default, it’s `5`. Use `returns=0` to remove the limit.

```
>>> zipcodes = search.by_state('IL', returns=0)
>>> len(zipcodes)
1249
```